# Show in AllDay slot even if event.allDay = false;

Tags: fullcalendar

If an event start on a date and ends on some other date (say, next date). I want to show such events in allDay slot but don't want to mark event.allDay = true;
Any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: To my knowledge this is not a possible function within fullCalendar, but maybe if you would elaborate a little more about what you are trying to accomplish and why the allDay event is not applicable, maybe we could help you accomplish you end goal.

Comment: I knew this is not a function on fullCalendar. But I wanted to alter the code of the plugin to meet my requirements.
I did it successfully. I've posted the solution bellow. Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the calendar code like this:

Find this method (for me it's on line#4467)

```
function renderEvents(events, modifiedEventId)
```

In this method find the following check:

```
if (events[i].allDay) { ... }
```

Replace it with this:

```
if (events[i].allDay || (events[i].end - events[i].start > 3600000) ) {
    // if event spans more than a day show it in allDay area
...
}
```

Now any events that span more than a day will be shown in allDay area even if they are not marked 'allDay'
This was my requirement I had to do it like this. I mentioned it here in case anyone else come here searching a similar solution.